# Stanford NLP Coref Resolution for Conversational Data

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to make some experiments with Stanford dcoref package on our conversational data. Our data contains usernames (speakers) and the utterances. Is it possible to give a structured data as input (instead of the raw text) to Stanford dcoref annotator? If yes, what should be the format of conversational input data?

Thank you,
-berfin

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this basic example to work:

```
<doc id="speaker-example-1">
<post author="Joe Smith" datetime="2018-02-28T20:10:00" id="p1">
I am hungry!
</post>
<post author="Jane Smith" datetime="2018-02-28T20:10:05" id="p2">
Joe Smith is hungry.
</post>
</doc>
```

I used these properties:

```
annotators = tokenize,cleanxml,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,coref

coref.conll = true
coref.algorithm = clustering

# Clean XML tags for SGM (move to sgm specific conf file?)
clean.xmltags = headline|dateline|text|post
clean.singlesentencetags = HEADLINE|DATELINE|SPEAKER|POSTER|POSTDATE
clean.sentenceendingtags = P|POST|QUOTE
clean.turntags = TURN|POST|QUOTE
clean.speakertags = SPEAKER|POSTER
clean.docIdtags = DOCID
clean.datetags = DATETIME|DATE|DATELINE
clean.doctypetags = DOCTYPE
clean.docAnnotations = docID=doc[id],doctype=doc[type],docsourcetype=doctype[source]
clean.sectiontags = HEADLINE|DATELINE|POST
clean.sectionAnnotations = sectionID=post[id],sectionDate=post[date|datetime],sectionDate=postdate,author=post[author],author=poster
clean.quotetags = quote
clean.quoteauthorattributes = orig_author
clean.tokenAnnotations = link=a[href],speaker=post[author],speaker=quote[orig_author]
clean.ssplitDiscardTokens = \\n|\\*NL\\*
```

Also this document has great info on the coref system:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html

I am looking into using the `neural` option on my example `.xml` document, but you might have to put your data into the `conll` format to run our neural coref with the `conll` settings.  The `conll` data has conversational data with speaker info among other document formats.

This document contains info on the CoNLL format you'd have to use for the `neural` algorithm to work.

CoNLL 2012 format: http://conll.cemantix.org/2012/data.html

You need to create a folder with a similar directory structure (but you can put your files in instead)

example:
`/Path/to/conll_2012_dir/v9/data/test/data/english/annotations/wb/eng/00/eng_0009.v9_auto_conll`

If you run this command:

```
java -Xmx20g edu.stanford.nlp.coref.CorefSystem -props speaker.properties
```

with these properties:

```
coref.algorithm = clustering
coref.conll = true
coref.conllOutputPath = /Path/to/output_dir
coref.data = /Path/to/conll_2012_dir
```

it will write conll output files to `/Path/to/output_dir`

That command should read in all files ending with `_auto_conll`

Comment: Thank you! Your post helped me a lot in this task.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for selecting the "clustering" algorithm instead of the "statistical" one. "Clustering" algorithm is also doing a statistical resolution task or is it a kind of neural system? I could not find useful information on Stanford's clustering coref algorithm.